Snowflake: SQL DENSE_RANK() not working as expected. Would there be an alternative?
I am trying to rank my table based on sku and rolling_inbound but there are quite a few other columns in the table which I believe is why I'm not seeing what I need.
For example:- When I run the code:
SELECT 
    week
    sku,
    units_sold,
    inbound,
    rolling_inbound,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sku, rolling_inbound ORDER BY week) AS sku_rank
FROM table


This is the result I am getting:



week
sku
units_sold
inbound
rolling_inbound
sku_rank




2024-01-01
a
10
30
30
1


2024-01-07
a
5
0
30
2


2024-01-14
a
7
0
30
3


2024-01-21
a
5
15
15
4


2024-01-28
a
3
0
15
5



But what I am trying to get is the following:



week
sku
units_sold
inbound
rolling_inbound
sku_rank




2024-01-01
a
10
30
30
1


2024-01-07
a
5
0
30
1


2024-01-14
a
7
0
30
1


2024-01-21
a
5
15
15
2


2024-01-28
a
3
0
15
2



I'm not entirely sure why this is happening, I think it is because the different non-unique rows.
Would there be a solution for this ? or an alternative that will allow me to rank as needed ?
Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks :)

Surely you meant DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY rolling_inbound DESC) https://dbfiddle.uk/U_xLiwbq Or what happens if the next few rows have say 40 in the rolling_inbound column?

Hey @Charlieface You're correct but also correct when 40 comes along where it rank incorrect :(

This actually looks to be more of a gaps and islands problem than a ranking.  It appears that you want to increment the sku_rank whenever the rolling_inbound changes within a given sku, as ordered by the week.
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(rolling_inbound)
                  OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY week) = rolling_inbound
                   THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS cnt
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    week
    sku,
    units_sold,
    inbound,
    rolling_inbound,
    SUM(cnt) OVER (PARTITION BY sku ORDER BY week) sku_rank
FROM cte
ORDER BY sku, week;

